# Can't able to use angular/cdk. How to resolve same?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I installed @angular/material and @angular/cdk for creating modal overlay. However, when I imported OverlayModule in app.module.ts it gives me following error:

```
Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3222:40-54
Can't import the named export 'ApplicationRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3240:11-38
Can't import the named export 'ComponentFactoryResolver' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3280:12-39
Can't import the named export 'ComponentFactoryResolver' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 410:11-19
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 443:15-23
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 1236:11-19
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 1265:15-23
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2735:11-19
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2768:15-23
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2834:11-19
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2861:15-23
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2934:11-19
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2961:15-23
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3089:11-19
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3118:15-23
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3250:11-19
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
9m
Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3293:15-23
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 4063:11-19
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 4092:15-23
Can't import the named export 'DOCUMENT' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3365:10-19
Can't import the named export 'Directive' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3764:10-19
Can't import the named export 'Directive' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2393:26-36
Can't import the named export 'ElementRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3350:11-24
Can't import the named export 'ElementRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3373:12-25
Can't import the named export 'ElementRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3407:29-41
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3410:30-42
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3413:22-34
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3416:22-34
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3419:30-42
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3422:35-47
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 442:14-20
Can't import the named export 'Inject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 1264:14-20
Can't import the named export 'Inject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2767:14-20
Can't import the named export 'Inject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2860:14-20
Can't import the named export 'Inject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2960:14-20
Can't import the named export 'Inject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3117:14-20
Can't import the named export 'Inject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3292:14-20
Can't import the named export 'Inject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3780:14-20
Can't import the named export 'Inject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 4091:14-20
Can't import the named export 'Inject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 427:10-20
Can't import the named export 'Injectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 1255:10-20
Can't import the named export 'Injectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2756:10-20
Can't import the named export 'Injectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2851:10-20
Can't import the named export 'Injectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2951:10-20
Can't import the named export 'Injectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3108:10-20
Can't import the named export 'Injectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3272:10-20
Can't import the named export 'Injectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 4082:10-20
Can't import the named export 'Injectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3329:50-64
Can't import the named export 'InjectionToken' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3246:11-22
Can't import the named export 'Injector' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3286:12-23
Can't import the named export 'Injector' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3792:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3796:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3800:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3804:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3808:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3812:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3816:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

mError: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3820:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3824:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3828:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3832:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3836:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3840:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3844:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3848:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3852:12-17m
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3856:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3860:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3864:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3868:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3872:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3254:11-22
Can't import the named export 'Location' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3298:12-23
Can't import the named export 'Location' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3949:10-18
Can't import the named export 'NgModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 408:11-20
Can't import the named export 'NgZone' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 438:12-21
Can't import the named export 'NgZone' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3248:11-20
Can't import the named export 'NgZone' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3288:12-21
Can't import the named export 'NgZone' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3786:14-22
Can't import the named export 'Optional' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3876:12-18
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3879:12-18
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3882:12-18
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3885:12-18
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3888:12-18
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3891:12-18
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 631:30-37
Can't import the named export 'Subject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 632:28-35
Can't import the named export 'Subject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 633:28-35
Can't import the named export 'Subject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 640:30-37
Can't import the named export 'Subject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 643:37-44
Can't import the named export 'Subject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 1334:32-39
Can't import the named export 'Subject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 634:28-40
Can't import the named export 'Subscription' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 1337:31-43
Can't import the named export 'Subscription' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3392:33-45
Can't import the named export 'Subscription' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3393:31-43
Can't import the named export 'Subscription' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3394:31-43
Can't import the named export 'Subscription' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3395:33-45
Can't import the named export 'Subscription' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3710:11-25
Can't import the named export 'TemplateRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3774:12-26
Can't import the named export 'TemplateRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3712:11-30
Can't import the named export 'ViewContainerRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3776:12-31
Can't import the named export 'ViewContainerRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 1098:64-69
Can't import the named export 'merge' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 709:31-35
Can't import the named export 'take' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 1098:54-63
Can't import the named export 'takeUntil' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3678:71-80
Can't import the named export 'takeWhile' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 412:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 1240:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2741:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2836:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2936:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3093:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3258:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3352:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3719:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3924:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 4067:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3756:13-36
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵNgOnChangesFeature' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3354:24-44
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵdefineDirective' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3721:27-47
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵdefineDirective' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 421:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 1249:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2750:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2845:0-27
91mCan't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2945:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3102:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3266:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3359:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3758:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3943:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 4076:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 398:29-50
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 1230:24-45
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2727:30-51
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2828:29-50
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2928:33-54
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3083:37-58
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3230:15-36
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3344:24-45
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

mError: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3702:27-48
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3918:21-42
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 4057:34-55
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 414:30-54
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 1242:25-49
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2743:31-55
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2838:30-54
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 2938:34-58
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
0m
Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3095:38-62
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3260:16-40
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 4069:35-59
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3935:21-43
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjector' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs 3926:21-43
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/bidi' in 'C:\Users\shrey\Desktop\angular\Shreyak_Jain_Solution\node_modules\@angular\cdk\fesm2015'

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/coercion' in 'C:\Users\shrey\Desktop\angular\Shreyak_Jain_Solution\node_modules\@angular\cdk\fesm2015'     

Error: ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/fesm2015/overlay.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/keycodes' in 'C:\Users\shrey\Desktop\angular\Shreyak_Jain_Solution\node_modules\@angular\cdk\fesm2015'
```